# How to pre-compile Deno script?

Tags: deno

Executing `deno run script.ts` first time is slow, and the second time is faster.

Is there some pre-compile command, to compile and cache scripts, but don't run it?

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch and compile modules into your local cache using `deno cache script.ts`.

You can also use `deno cache --reload script.ts` to invalidate the cache and then refetch and recompile.

Reference: [Reloading modules | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/reloading_modules)

Comment: Thanks, but fetchng modules is not the same as compiling, I don't know for sure, but it feels like deno also somehow caches compiled scripts

Comment: Correct. And this process is part of the cache. The cache contains raw sources and compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile a Deno script into a standalone binary using [`deno compile`](https://deno.land/manual/tools/compiler).

```
deno compile https://deno.land/std/examples/welcome.ts
./welcome # Run executable
```